# Preloader Conflicting with Existing Javascript

Tags: javascript, preloader, window.onunload

I'm not very skilled at implementing javascript and there seems to be a problem with the preloader working on a certain page on my site. It seems to be conflicting with another script which is loading content.

Both scripts work independently but not together. I'm sure it's something simple but I just don't know javascript well enough.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).on('load', function() { // makes sure the whole site is loaded 
$('#status').fadeOut(); // will first fade out the loading animation 
$('#preloader').delay(350).fadeOut('slow'); // will fade out the white DIV that covers the website. 
$('body').delay(350).css({'overflow':'visible'});})</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
$(".about").fadeTo(300, 1);
});
</script>
```

Comment: difficult to know the problem. how do you mean "conflicting"? can you create a reproducible example and explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I am just trying to get the preloader to work before the other script initiates. Do the scripts both look like they'd be compatible?